# Is there a way to recover crashed Choregraphe projects?

Tags: ubuntu, crash, recovery, choregraphe

I am working with Choregraphe and I recently connected two boxes causing my computer to crash. I had to hard restart the computer and now I am unable to access the project. Anytime I try to open it in choregraphe the application just crashes back to desktop. Other projects are unaffected. I am very very new to Choregraphe and I have not found many resources documenting this problem and how to recover from it. I figured there may be some brilliant minds here with suggestions for how to move forward.

I have tried to open all of the various project files in regular vim to see if there was something I could hotfix on my own to no avail. I have tried to search through the troubleshooting documents for Choregraphe but have had no luck finding documentation relating to this type of issue.

**UPDATE:
I have figured out that my Behavior.xar file had been overwritten during the crash. It is now an empty file, and this is why Choregraphe will not open the project. Does anyone know of a Way to recover this file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already upload it in your robot using the play button you can recover it in the .lastuploaded behavior folder in /home/nao/.local/apps/PackageManager...

Comment: Would this still be valid even if other projects have been uploaded as well? I was worried the entire choregraphe was bunked so I tested another project to make sure the NAO was still functioning.

Comment: if you open other choregraphe project AND upload one in NAO, then the previous one is lost...